# Run playbook on multiple users on a server

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have inventory file which has multiple users for a server, like below.

```
[TEST]
server1 ansible_user=user1
server1 ansible_user=user2
server1 ansible_user=user3
server1 ansible_user=user4
```

When I run playbook using this inventory, it only runs on "server1 ansible_user=user4", ignoring first 3 users. How can I run playbook on all 4 users?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this inventory you have **one** inventory entry `server1` and with each new line you override `ansible_user` variable.

If you really want (what is the use case) to make this happen, use host aliasing:

```
[TEST]
s1_u1 ansible_host=server1 ansible_user=user1
s1_u2 ansible_host=server1 ansible_user=user2
s1_u3 ansible_host=server1 ansible_user=user3
s1_u4 ansible_host=server1 ansible_user=user4
```

But be prepared to possible concurrency issues, like APT lock for example.

Comment: Worked for me! I am just copying files so I am not worried about concurrency.